# Cypress Test automation for Oracle ADF application

Tags: oracle, cypress

I want to know if we can use Cypress UI Test automation framework for testing Oracle ADF applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for a more descriptive "need". Yes, it is possible to test "browser-based / web" applications created via Oracle ADF (assumption is you are not referring to desktop-based or mobile applications).

If you are testing the back-end (e.g. database) then it might be possible too (although not the best use case for Cypress) as long as the tests are scripted via JS. For example, AWS DB have their own JS SDK's which you can integrate with Cypress. SQL Server has this package as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-sql-server